# xyzzyで複数箇所に同時に同じ内容を入力できますか？

Tags: xyzzy

SublimeTextやRubyMineにある機能で複数箇所をカーソルで選択して、その状態で入力すると同時に複数箇所にテキスト入力できる機能がありますが、`xyzzy`でそのような機能を追加する方法はありますか？

Comment: 手元の『入門xyzzy』やNetInstallerまわりをざっと確認しましたが、マルチセレクションに該当する機能は存在しないようです。

Comment: そうなんですね、残念。調べていただいてありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

css でならあります。
以下のemmetのサブ機能で近いものがあります。

tabstop機能の発展で分離していますが、
普通のマルチ―カーソル機能としてはマウスで指定できる形ではないので、公開されてません。

> **emmetも使えるテキストエディター【xyzzy】 | SCAITY(スケイティー)**
> http://edutainment-fun.com/hidemaru/xyzzy/emmet%E3%82%82%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B%E3%83%86%E3%82%AD%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%82%A8%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%80%90xyzzy%E3%80%91_2827.html#i-13
>
> サブ関数は色々独自実装です。
> ◇emmet-reflecting-css-value
> ベンダープレフィックスで同じような複数行の設定があるときに、書き換える前に
> コマンドを実行するとタブストップが効きます。変更してからは動作しません。